# Change layout in Magento 2 before page load

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

I am trying to change a page layout before the loading of a page in Magento 2.

I want this layout to be loaded on the base of the configuration.

If you have any example available feel free to drop it in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using an observer.

> layout_load_before
> this event means changing the layout before the pages load.

create etc/[frontend/]events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="layout_load_before_abc" instance="Verndor\ModuleName\Observer\AddHandle" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create an Observer/AddHandle.php

```
<?php
namespace Verndor\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;
use Verndor\ModuleName\Helper\Data;

class AddHandle implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    private Data $helper;

    /**
     * @param Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Data $helper
    ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer): void
    {
        /** @var LayoutInterface $layout */
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        
        if ($this->helper->moduleEnabled()) {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle("xyz_index_index"); //Name of layout_file_name.xml
        } else {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle("abc_index_index"); //Name of layout_file_name.xml
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_front_send_response_before">
        <observer name="layout_load_before_anypage" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddHandel" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/AddHandel.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class AddHandel implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer): void
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle("xyz_index_index"); //layout_file_name.xml Name
    }
}
```